# How to define the concept of $\phi$-related vector-valued forms.

Tags: differential-geometry

If $\phi:M\rightarrow N$ is a smooth map between manifolds and $c_1$ is a vector-valued form on $M$, i.e. $c_1\in\Omega(M,E)$ where $E$ is a vector bundle over $M$, and $c_2$ is a vector-valued form on $N$, i.e. $c_2\in\Omega(N,V)$ where $V$ is another vector bundle over $N$, how can i define that $c_1$ and $c_2$ are $\phi$-related?

My problem is how to map a vector in $E$ in a vector in $V$. I have to fix basis?

Thanks for all help me.

Comment: How are you defining "$\phi$-related vector bundle-valued forms"?

Comment: I’ve never heard of $\phi$-related forms (forget vector-valued). This notion usually applies to vector fields, since they don’t in general push forward. But forms always pull back.